# How can I get a value which I receive over Request.Form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, typescript, form-data

So in my Frontend I pass an Object which has a PersonId and a FormData object.

```
const formData = new FormData();

for (let file of files){
    formData.append(file.name, file,);
}
formData.append('currentId',this.UserId.toString());

const uploadReq = new HttpRequest('POST', 'https://localhost:5001/api/file',formData, {
      reportProgress: true,

});
```

The FormData Object I receive in my backend with this line:

```
var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
```

The question is how do I get the currentId value?

An approach of mine was this:

```
var PersonId = Request.Form.Keys;
```

But that gives me this back and I don't know how to get this value.

[image: image of watch window]

Comment: Seeing your Javascript it looks like `Request.Form["currentId"]` would be sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a variable of type StringValues:

`StringValues id;`

Then use that variable the following:

`Request.Form.TryGetValue("currentId", out id);`